# React native and redux global environment variables

Tags: react-native, redux

I am trying to find the best way to store environment variables such as API and CDN servers DNS.

I saw my other answers, most recommended on one of the following:

1. Store in `global` - Don't like it. Hate throwing stuff to global, much rather using proper scopes. Also, seems a bit of an anti-pattern, but if you disagree I'de love to hear your arguments.
2. Keep the environment data in a separate file, and load current environment from that file - won't work for me as those are dynamic variables that might change (switching to another environment, CDN changes etc.)
3. Pass it via props - I don't like the idea of passing the config down 7 components whenever I need the CDN to show an image.

Ideally, I would like to have an option to `import` a lib in different places in the app. Basically something like this:

```
# when app starts, somewhere in the master container
import envConfig from './envConfig'

# load config from API
API.loadconfig().than((data) => envConfig.setConfig(data))
```

Then, in other files

```
import envConfig from './envConfig'
const cdn = envConfig.cdn;
```

Does that make any sense? is there a better way to achieve the same goal?

How can I make an import module to have a state?

Comment: If you're using Redux why do you need to pass it down manually? When you map the component's props to state, include them. (Caveat: don't know anything about React Native really.) That aside, for globals, I don't see a big issue with putting a global config into global scope.

Comment: Yea, I thought to do something like that but then all API calls are in another file, and that file doesn't know what redux is. So, if I'll use the store I will have to send it to the API file every time I want to make a call... for now I will use global, but I never liked the idea of global variables.

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I had to pass down some global variables so that I can access them anywhere in my app. Here's how I achieved that-

1. Wrap your application inside a global component like `App`.
2. Render children inside that App like this-

`<div>
  {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { ...this.props.globalState })}
</div>`

If you're using `Navigator` in your app, you can pass global variables through the `Navigator`. Please refer to [this](https://github.com/KarandikarMihir/IOT/blob/master/src/main.js) file to see how to exactly implement that. It's 4 months old code, please forgive me for that.

Good luck!